# Creating a dictionary of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python

I'm getting a number of python dictionaries of products from a query as follows

```
{u'rating': 0.0, u'name': u'Samsung NP550P5C-S02IN (3rd Gen Ci7/ 8GB/ 1TB/ Win7 HP/ 2GB Graphics)', u'price': 0.0, u'popularity': 9, u'brand_id': 1, u'category_id': 3, u'id': 3794}

{u'rating': 10.0, u'name': u'Samsung NP300E5A-A08IN Laptop (2nd Gen Pentium Dual Core/ 2GB/ 500GB/ Win7 HB)', u'price': 0.0, u'popularity': 23, u'brand_id': 1, u'category_id': 3, u'id': 3825}

{u'rating': 0.0, u'name': u'Samsung NP-RV515-A02IN Laptop (APU Dual Core/ 2GB/ 500GB/ Win7 HB)', u'price': 0.0, u'popularity': 26, u'brand_id': 1, u'category_id': 3, u'id': 3826}

{u'rating': 9.2, u'name': u'Samsung NP355V5C-S03IN Laptop (APU Quad Core A8/ 6GB/ 750GB/ Win7 HP/ 1GB Graphics)', u'price': 0.0, u'popularity': 17, u'brand_id': 1, u'category_id': 3, u'id': 3889}
```

I need to store them somehow with their key and associated values. I tried to store them in an empty dictionary as follows.

```
product_list = {}
for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
    product_list.update(hit["_source"])
print product_list
```

But this ended up adding only the last dictionary because the keys of all the dictionary are the same. What would be the ideal way to store these together? How can I make a dictionary of dictionaries for this?

Comment: You already have them in a list. In what way is that not satisfactory?

Comment: `product_dict[dict['id']] = dict`

Comment: Are you sure you want a dictionary of dictionaries? What would you do with the resulting nested dictionary that a list of dictionaries doesn't do for you?

Comment: I think you need to specify how the end result should look like and if you can how this is going to be used.

Comment: If their keys are all the same, I don't understand why you want to put them in a dictionary with their key as key.

Comment: @NPE Sorry, I've updated the question. It isn't a list of dictionaries. I've added the exact code that I'm using.

Comment: What is the format of res?

Comment: @zbs It's a dictionary.

Comment: Can you specify what does it contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for you as user2923089 explain in his answer you need to use a list of dictionaries.

Why do you need to use a dictionary of dictionary ? Do hou have some kind of data classification ? If all your data is like:

`{u'rating': 0.0, u'name': u'Samsung NP550P5C-S02IN (3rd Gen Ci7/ 8GB/ 1TB/ Win7 HP/ 2GB Graphics)', u'price': 0.0, u'popularity': 9, u'brand_id': 1, u'category_id': 3, u'id': 3794}`

Just like that repeated x times, you don't need to use a dictonary of dictionaries, you need to use a list of dictionaries like :

```
full_list = [
{u'rating': 0.0, u'name': u'Samsung NP550P5C-S02IN (3rd Gen Ci7/ 8GB/ 1TB/ Win7 HP/ 2GB Graphics)', u'price': 0.0, u'popularity': 9, u'brand_id': 1, u'category_id': 3, u'id': 3794}, 
{u'rating': 10.0, u'name': u'Samsung NP300E5A-A08IN Laptop (2nd Gen Pentium Dual Core/ 2GB/ 500GB/ Win7 HB)', u'price': 0.0, u'popularity': 23, u'brand_id': 1, u'category_id': 3, u'id': 3825}, 
{u'rating': 0.0, u'name': u'Samsung NP-RV515-A02IN Laptop (APU Dual Core/ 2GB/ 500GB/ Win7 HB)', u'price': 0.0, u'popularity': 26, u'brand_id': 1, u'category_id': 3, u'id': 3826}, 
{u'rating': 9.2, u'name': u'Samsung NP355V5C-S03IN Laptop (APU Quad Core A8/ 6GB/ 750GB/ Win7 HP/ 1GB Graphics)', u'price': 0.0, u'popularity': 17, u'brand_id': 1, u'category_id': 3, u'id': 3889}
]
```

also maybe you could append to that `full_list` any data at any time like:

```
new_data = {u'rating': 0.0, u'name': u'Samsung NP550P5C-S02IN (3rd Gen Ci7/ 8GB/ 1TB/ Win7 HP/ 2GB Graphics)', u'price': 0.0, u'popularity': 9, u'brand_id': 1, u'category_id': 3, u'id': 3794}
full_list.append(new_data)
```

---

**Why list of dictionaries ?**

If you have different kind of data, like some data with extra values, or with less values or different values, maybe a dictionary of dictionaries like:

```
full_data = {'normal_data':[normal_data_list], 'extra_value': [extra_value_list], 'whatever':whatever_you_need}
```

So you will have 3 or N different list of dictionaries, just in case you need it. If you only have N dictionaries with same data, a list will be the best choice for you, because you don't need a key (like in a dictionary) to get the list of data. Using your code, if you have all the data in res['hits']['hits'] you can create the full data list like:

```
product_list = []
for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
    product_list.append(hit["_source"])
print product_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to key your dictionary using a unique identifier (I'd use the Id, that's what its there for) and then you can use the names as the keys on the inner dictionaries so your outer dictionary should link the id value (as the key) to an inner dictionary (as the value) which links the names of the vields (as the key) to their values. This results in a unique key in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

In that solution i guess that field 'id' is unique.

```
a = {u'rating': 0.0, u'name': u'Samsung NP550P5C-S02IN (3rd Gen Ci7/ 8GB/ 1TB/ Win7 HP/ 2GB Graphics)', u'price': 0.0, u'popularity': 9, u'brand_id': 1, u'category_id': 3, u'id': 3794}
b = {u'rating': 10.0, u'name': u'Samsung NP300E5A-A08IN Laptop (2nd Gen Pentium Dual Core/ 2GB/ 500GB/ Win7 HB)', u'price': 0.0, u'popularity': 23, u'brand_id': 1, u'category_id': 3, u'id': 3825}
c = {u'rating': 0.0, u'name': u'Samsung NP-RV515-A02IN Laptop (APU Dual Core/ 2GB/ 500GB/ Win7 HB)', u'price': 0.0, u'popularity': 26, u'brand_id': 1, u'category_id': 3, u'id': 3826}
d = {u'rating': 9.2, u'name': u'Samsung NP355V5C-S03IN Laptop (APU Quad Core A8/ 6GB/ 750GB/ Win7 HP/ 1GB Graphics)', u'price': 0.0, u'popularity': 17, u'brand_id': 1, u'category_id': 3, u'id': 3889}

product_list = {}

for i in [a,b,c,d]:
    product_list[i.pop('id')] = i
```